# Not able to Understand how to proceed with AgensGraph_v2.5.0

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I am new to AgensGraph and I am done with the installation in Windows. After going through the installation guide,

```
agens=# create graph test_graph;
CREATE GRAPH
agens=# set graph_path=test_graph;
SET
agens=# create(:test {name:’lastNotice’});
UPDATE 1
agens=# match(a:test) return a;
                a
---------------------------------
 test[3.1]{"name": "lastNotice"}
(1 row)
```

I got this and I am not sure how to proceed ahead with this, plus I want to integrate it with SQL as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write your cypher query in SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('<enter_graph_name_here>', $$ 
MATCH (n) return n
 $$)
AS (result agtype);
```

Comment: I think she's talking about AgensGraph not AGE, they have a different syntax.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion